# asp.net repeater with marquee and label tags

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a asp project, and i want to display the values from database (Sql server) into marquee tag one by one. After some searching i am able to make this below code.

```
 <asp:Repeater id="newsrepeater" runat="server">   
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="labelnews" text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' runat="server">             
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The code works , only issue is the values from the list display all together. E.g if there are news1 and news2 are there then news1news2 are displayed while i want to display news1 and news 2 one after each other. and they will repeat. Any Suggestions please.

Comment: Why don't you add a `<br>`? Or `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Thank you answering, but i dont want the space between two news i.e news1 news2 , rather then i want to display a news after one another. First it display news1 and then news2 at the end of news1 and repeat this process.

Comment: Are you trying to show just one at a time and cycle through them? If that's the case, I wouldn't use a repeater - I'd set up with an Update Panel and a Timer. When the timer ticks, you can have it show the next item in your data source list. You could also accomplish this "cycle" by having your repeater tell Jquery/Javascript the potential items, and have Jquery loop through them.

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
<div id="Hot_News" >
            <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="2" behavior="alternate" onmouseover="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 6, 0);">
            <asp:Repeater ID="rep_marq" runat="server" >                    
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <ul class="marquee">
                        <li class="marquee_li">
                            <a href='<%# Eval("NewsID","../Public_Pages/ShowNewsPage.aspx?NID={0}") %>'>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("NewsTitr") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            </marquee>                
        </div>
```

and in code behind:

```
public void fillrepeter()
{
    try
    {
        var db = new DataClassesDataContext();
        var fill = (db.TblNews.Select(p => p)).Take(5).ToList();
        if (fill != null)
        {
            rep_marq.DataSource = fill;
            rep_marq.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```